# a software license for amazon ec2

Tags: licensing, amazon-ec2, cloud

We are trying to build a cluster server to run on Amazon EC2.

Currently the way how our license works is that we get customer's machine information(like cpu, memory, mac address, etc) to identify the machine and to lock our server to run on this machine only. The individual servers can run as a cluster. So we provide a license for each node.

But this model doesn't work on Amazon EC2 and other cloud provider. I am wondering how we can solve this problem.

Possible solution I can think of is that:
1) Host a license server that all the customers' server need to talk to this license server
2) Get some kinds of ID from Amazon. This approach seems more realistic as of now.

Regarding the approach #2, does Amazon provide some API for us to get this account's ID?

If you have any other ideas about a license model to work on public cloud or private cloud, please also let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to ec2 but you could programmatically get the instance ID but I think you'd need to install ec2 tools on the instance itself and have their information(there maybe another way to get it).  That ID seems unique(you have to provide to amazon so they can find your instance for support) and it doesn't change if you stop your instance(not sure if they terminate and re-launch).  or you can use security certificates to make sure its unique in this case.

What is the current licensing? Can they only run it on one machine or only one machine at a time?  If its one machine then you'll probably have to map it to some unique ID from amazon(like what I mentioned above) but if its one machine at a time then you can have it verify its information with your servers upon startup and if another server connects using their license you can disable them.

On a side note, I don't think this is a good idea in general.  If you look at big companies like microsoft or oracle, they generally don't do much to prevent you from breaching their licenses. This is because when you get audited you'll have to pay anyway and going through the licensing process can make people not install their software as freely(my experience, when we needed a oracle server and set it up but didn't license it then during our yearly audit had to pay them a crap load. Many of our development testing turned into production which caused us to pay even more). With my current company, we do this(monitor usage but don't stop people from installing and then bill them after) and its been very profitable.   If this idea works for you then consider the adice above but instead of disabling the service just monitor it and then have your sales rep start the conversation with them.

Comment: Thanks. Your approach is like to host a license server. We are not a website. We provide software to customer. They can install them on their machine. It would be difficult to monitor the usage if not impossible. I understand this is the best solution, but provided limited resources, I am looking for other easier solutions like using ID to limit my software to be installed in this account only. Our current licensing model has been working well for a long time. We are recently moving to public cloud deployment. That is why we are looking for some other models to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know if their usage will change as they are using it in the cloud? I.e. if they run it all the time currently, will that behavior continue in the cloud? or do you think they will turn the servers on and off and deploy in different locations,etc..

Comment: The reason I ask, is if they plan to just run it all the time, why not maybe try using a security cert generated against each new machine?

Comment: It depends on the load of their server, Amazon will launch new node on demand. For the security cert, they need to generate every time they restart the server right? Then we need to provide a way to authenticate the cert either through a license server or manually. So it is actually the same problem, is it?

Comment: not exactly. The state of the server is maintained if its not terminated(and they are storing it on the EBS part of their OS image not on the Ephemeral storage). So the cert will remain the same but I'm not sure if they clone the instance if the cert will remain the same(I don't think so).  But you have another problem, if they are launching a new server because of load and don't have enough server licenses should they be blocked? or do you let them go unlicensed during the increase load? If they use certs, they can have unique ones on multiple servers as long as they are not terminated.

Comment: For the last problem, our server will handle it. Even if more servers launched, we will not launch any factory server to do the real work if they already reached the limit of allowed work unit.

Comment: Then the cert approach is probably best. Have your program generate one during install and have your servers verify activation against it.  Tell them they can turn off the server but if they terminate it they will have to reactive the product(maybe a phone call to you to delete the old cert from your system).  If its production, then I can see servers being turned off because of demand but not being terminated(its the same as formatting your server)

Answer (score 0):

With the AWS marketplace Amazon does try to solve some of these problems. From my understanding how this would work for you is, you offer your software as an AMI via the marketplace and Amazon then includes the license fee in the hourly price for the instance + AMI.

Here's a link for more info https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/help/200899830/ref=gtw_r1